# Can't log out of my site

Tags: cookies, logout

I can't log out of my site's front end.  When I try to do so, I get the following message:

```
The following errors were encountered

   • You are not authorized to perform this action
```

If I delete my cookies, then I will be logged out.

I've tried all three setting settings for Website Session Type in the Admin section of the Control Panel, clearing the cookies between tests, but I get the same error when I try to log out.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same thing. {path='logout'} does not work

This finally ended up working. I use Solspace User, not sure if that is related..

```
<a href="{path='?ACT=16'}&XID={XID_HASH}">Log out</a>
```

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of User? Which EE version are you using?